# How to add some html between LI generated by Yii cmenu widget?

Tags: yii

I wish to add something like this:

```
menuitem1 / menuitem2 / menuitem3
```

I need to add that slash `/` between the `LI` generated elements.

Any clue how to make it?

I've tried this:

```
array('label'=>'About us', 'url'=>array('/about/index'), 'template'=> '/'),
```

But I get this generated:

```
<li class="active">/</li>
```

Am I miss placing the `template` attribute?

Any other way, because, / is not a template?

**UPDATE**
Got it:

```
array('label'=>'About us', 'url'=>array('/about/index'), 'template'=> '{menu} <span>/</span>'),
```

This will generate a `span` **after** the `li` elements.

If anyone has a better way of doing this, please share.

**UPDATE TWO:**
While this works, the markup generated with be invalid. So a pseudo-element could be an option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's bad HTML.  There shouldn't be any markup in between `<li>` elements.  If you would like to have slashes in between your menu items, I would recommend you either use another widget to display your menu items (something that doesn't use list items), or that you play with the css pseudo classes, `:after` and `:before`, to include slashes where you want them.

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_before.asp
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_after.asp

Of course, another option would be to add an image of a slash as the background of your element.  I just wouldn't call that the best option.

Comment: Thanks. Based on what are you saying "there shouldn't be any markup in between the `li`? I don't see anything wrong adding html elements like `span` between li elements. The `pseudo elements` while may be an alternative, aren't supported by "not so old" browsers, like IE7 and has some bugs on IE8. I believe. About the widget... just to think that I should setup a widget to add slashes on Yii... it makes me nervous. ;)

Comment: If you're wanting to insert the slash INSIDE the li like this: `<li>/</li>`, that's alright.  If you're wanting to do that I can change my answer.  Otherwise, this is invalid `<li></li>/<li></li>`. http://grab.by/sZJO.  Those pages I linked to indicate :after and :before should work in IE8, and I haven't had problems before.  And IE7 is dead. http://theie7countdown.com/.  I would recommend no longer supporting it.

Comment: I see. About IE8 it seems we have issues using z-index and pseudo-elements. I will try those pseudo-elements anyway, since I don't expect to use z-index here.